# Youtube API javascript errors (can't find .swf file)

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-api

Here is the site. Looks like I get three js erros.

http://thomaspalumbo.com/mostlymozart/

[image: my js console]

The "next" button is unresponsive at certain times. I've done some research but I can't figure out how to fix these errors. All my js is in my index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

Website is loading just fine for me. Are you sure it isn't just an error on your side?

Comment: Could be. I should have explained more though. The "next" button is unresponsive at certain times. And I felt like this error getting that .swf file was weird and should be corrected.

Comment: @user1857734 As you can see [here](http://puu.sh/1TXhh/24add94f41) I pressed next plenty of times, and it always worked.

Comment: Ok. Anyone know why my if else statement doesn't seem to make a difference? 

`function nextVideo() {
      var num = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
      console.log(num);
      player.setShuffle(true);
      
      if (num >= 2) {
      player.nextVideo();
      player.loadPlaylist({
       list: '90s rap',
       listType: 'search',
                   })   
    player.playVideo();
    }
    
    else if (num < 2) {
     player.nextVideo();
     player.loadPlaylist({
       list: 'mozart',
       listType:'search',
                   })   
    player.playVideo();
    }
      }
`